# SharePoint Python Module Unable to Import

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to install and import the "sharepoint" package for Python to use in some simple code.  I was able to do a pip install sharepoint, but now when I try to run the import in my code, I'm getting a module not found error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0bf1daccee80> in <module>
     42 from win32com.client import Dispatch
     43 #import sharepoint
---> 44 from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sharepoint'
```

Is there something I'm missing in the pip install process?  The documentation for the package doesn't say I need anything else.

EDIT:  sys.path is

```
['C:\\Users\\my_name\\Documents\\Project Group\\Project1\\Project1 Documents\\Lists', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\python37.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda', '', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\my_name\\.ipython']
```

pip version is pip 20.3.1 from C:\Users\my_name.anaconda\32-Bit\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python on your system?  What is the exact command you're using to run this code?

Comment: I only have one version on my computer.  The commands are:

import sharepoint
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener

Both are failing individually.

Comment: No, I meant how are you running python?  Do you type something like `python myscript.py` on the command line?  Or do you use an IDE?  Or some other way?

Comment: Oh I'm running it through Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Please update the question to show the output of this python code: `import sys; print(sys.path)` and also this command: `pip --version`

Comment: I think you should be installing packages with the `conda` command, not `pip`.

Comment: Error:
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - sharepoint
Current channels
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

Comment: Sorry for the poor pasting quality.